# How to Instantiate player bullet on leftside in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

In my unity 2D game I've instantiate bullet with player direction but bullet bullet instantiate on right side of player i try to bullet instantiate on player left side.this is my player bullet

```
public Rigidbody2D playerWeapon;


void Start(){

    InvokeRepeating ("PlayerWeapon",1.0f,1.0f);
}

void PlayerWeapon()
{
        Rigidbody2D bPrefab = Instantiate (playerWeapon, new Vector3 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity) as Rigidbody2D;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by left and right side? You want to instantiate bullet to where the player is facing?

Comment: yes exact this...

Comment: In my code bullet instantiate perfect but behind of player I want to instantiate bullet to player facing.

Comment: Where is the player reference? Is the script above attached to the player?

Comment: I attached  bullet instantiate script to the player object.

Comment: Just realized this is 2D. So your character is either facing left or right? If so, you want to instantiate/shoot the bullet depending on the direction it is facing?

Comment: yes, my player face on left side but bullet shoot on right side.

Comment: Try my solution and let me know if it is spawning in the correct position now.

Comment: thanks...i try it.

Comment: @ Programmer i try your solution but still same issue occur.

Comment: Do you mind uploading a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: @Programmer Sorry. I've cannot be upload image.

Comment: Check my edit and the new function code below it. If that doesn't work then I can't help further because I don't know what result the solution I provided is yielding. I can only see that from a screenshot. Happy coding!

Comment: @ Programmer Thanks ...I try to upload screenshot but in this site cannot be allow uploaded screen shot..

Answer (score 0):

Using `transform.forward` should do it. You can also use an offset to modify the distance the bullet should be spawned from the player's distance. Try the code below:

```
public Rigidbody2D playerWeapon;

void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("PlayerWeapon", 1.0f, 1.0f);
}

void PlayerWeapon()
{
    float offset = 5;
    Vector3 plyrPos = transform.position;
    Quaternion plyrRot = transform.rotation;
    Vector3 plyrDir = transform.forward;
    Vector3 spawnPos = plyrPos + plyrDir * offset;
    Rigidbody2D bPrefab = Instantiate(playerWeapon, spawnPos, plyrRot) as Rigidbody2D;
}
```

**EDIT**:

You could also do this instead:

```
void PlayerWeapon()
{
    float shootSpeed = 10f;
    float offset = 5;
    Rigidbody2D bPrefab = Instantiate(playerWeapon, transform.position + (offset * transform.forward), transform.rotation) as Rigidbody2D;
    bPrefab.velocity = transform.forward * shootSpeed;
}
```

If it is still going in the wrong direction, flip the `shootSpeed` value to `-10`, try again and also flip `offset` to `-5`. This will likely fix your problem.